# GitLab Runner Disconnecting During Pipeline Execution

Tags: powershell, iis, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

We're experiencing an issue with our GitLab Runner on our QA environment where it goes offline during pipeline execution. The Runner attempts to send PATCH requests to the GitLab server but times out with the following error message:

ERROR: Appending trace to coordinator... error couldn't execute PATCH against [GitLab Server API URL]: read tcp [Runner's IP]->[GitLab Server's IP]: wsarecv: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

We're running the GitLab Runner on a Windows server, and our GitLab instance is hosted on a AWS.

Thank you!

Here's what we've tried so far:

Checked network connectivity between the Runner and the GitLab server (both servers can ping each other, and Test-NetConnection in PowerShell is successful)
Confirmed that the necessary ports (80 and 443) are open in firewall rules on both the Runner and GitLab servers
Restarted the GitLab Runner service and the entire VM
Checked system and GitLab Runner logs for additional clues
Compared configurations with our Dev environment, where the Runner works fine. Both environments appear to be set up the same way, except for minor differences in domain network settings (the Dev environment has an active domain network, while the QA does not).
The issue persists despite these efforts, and we're currently at a loss as to what's causing the Runner to disconnect from the GitLab server. If anyone has any insight or suggestions, we would greatly appreciate it.